# When passing executable= to Popen, sys.executable is empty in child

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute python from a virtualenv using Popen, but it takes the one from `/usr/bin` (at least that what I'm thinking, see output below):

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: proc = subprocess.Popen(['my_program', '-c', 'import sys; print sys.executable; print sys.path;'], executable='/home/user/.pypy/bin/pypy', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   ...: print proc.stdout.read(1024)
   ...: 

['', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib_pypy/__extensions__', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib_pypy', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/pypy2.7/dist-packages', '/home/user', '/usr/lib/pypy/dist-packages']


In [3]: proc = subprocess.Popen(['/home/user/.pypy/bin/pypy', '-c', 'import sys; print sys.executable; print sys.path;'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   ...: print proc.stdout.read(1024)
   ...: 
/home/user/.pypy/bin/pypy
['', '/home/user/.pypy/lib_pypy/__extensions__', '/home/user/.pypy/lib_pypy', '/home/user/.pypy/lib-python/2.7', '/home/user/.pypy/lib-python/2.7/lib-tk', '/home/user/.pypy/lib-python/2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib_pypy', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/lib-tk', '/home/user/.pypy/site-packages', '/home/user']
```

you can see that without the `executable` parameter all looks fine (both executable and sys.path. but once I'm using the parameter the sys.executable is empty string and the sys.path is the once of the system's pypy.

I'm ok with running without the `executable` parameter, as long there is another way to change the process name (I failed to find how to do that)

Comment: Why are you even using the `executable` argument?

Comment: `sys.executable` is only provided by the child process on a best-effort basis. The *parent* process is pretty much always going to honor it correctly -- it's hard to get "pass this as the exact first argument to the `execve()` syscall, distinct from the first element in the list of strings in the second argument" wrong -- but whether the *child* process can correctly detect what was passed there depends on a bunch of implementation details.

Comment: By way of demonstrating that you can reproduce the behavior at hand without using the `subprocess` module, or even having the parent process running Python at all, you can run `(exec -a /home/user/.pypy/bin/pypy my_program -c 'import sys; print sys.executable; print sys.path')` in bash to do the exact same thing as the first `subprocess.Popen()` call in your question.

Comment: As far as I understood from python's doc, the `executable` only causes

"On POSIX, the args name becomes the display name for the executable in utilities such as ps"

which is what i'm looking for. note that `my_program` should be the display name, and it is not a real program

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I used `sys.executable` as indication to the fact the virtualenv's executable isn't the executable that really running. also, I failed to use the `exec` command you gave in the comment, probably because "my_program" isn't a real file or lack of my understanding how `exec` is working

Comment: @eplaut, to be clear, `exec -a somename someprog` in bash starts the executable named `someprog` thinking it has (which is to say, with an `argv[0]` of) the name `somename`. It does not require `somename` to actually exist. This is the same thing accomplished by using `executable=` in `subprocess.Popen()`, where `args[0]` is the name that the program is told it has, and the argument to `executable=` is the file the OS is actually told to execute (replace the subprocess image with).

Comment: @user2357112, I'm trying to change the display name of the child process. this is how I've done it until now, and I thought it worth to check why it works only with `/usr/bin/python` and not on the virtualenv's one. If there is better way to change display name, I will be glad to hear it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks. I think the order of arguments in the previous comment was wrong. anyway, I understand that the problem is how the virtualenv loads the `sys.path` rather than the executable been launch. any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: Agreed that I got the order of arguments wrong in the initial comment. Re: `sys.path`, I'd generally tend to take more direct control via the environment, rather than trying to rely on DWIM magic. Activating a virtualenv doesn't do anything special, it just sets environment variables; you can force them to specific values when spawning a subprocess as-needed.